The meaning(s) of 'She couldn't buy a car yesterday.'
I am wondering what a standalone sentence 'She couldn't buy a car yesterday.' might mean:

'I don't know. There is no way I will believe that she bought a car yesterday.'
''I don't know. It is possible that she didn't buy a car yesterday.'
'I know that she tried to buy a car yesterday but failed.'
'I know that she would have failed to buy a car yesterday even if she had tried to.'


It means (3).  For (1), "She can't have bought..." - for (4), "She couldn't have bought..."

@KateBunting: It can sometimes also mean (4) - in the case where she didn't try to buy a car yesterday because she knew she would fail if she did.

(4) wouldn't make sense as a standalone sentence (read the question) although it would certainly work in some contexts.

The meaning of "She couldn't buy a car yesterday" is that she was unable to buy a car yesterday. Usually it means that she tried and failed (your example three), but maybe she became sick and was unable to even try.  You would use it when you know that she intended to buy a car but was prevented.
You appear to be mixing this up with "She couldn't have bought a car yesterday". This is what you would say when you want to express disbelief in the claim that she bought a car yesterday.

She couldn't have bought a car yesterday. I saw her post that she was in a different city all day.

This roughly corresponds with example 1.
It would also be used if you were certain that buying a car was impossible, which isn't a fundamentally different meaning, and corresponds to example 4.

She couldn't have bought a car yesterday because all the car shops were closed for the holiday.

For example 2 you might say "I don't think she bought a car yesterday."

It may be worth noting that "she wasn't able to buy a car [yesterday]" is the past tense form of "she can't buy a car [now]".  English has lots of subtle differences in meaning between "can't" and "couldn't" and variations thereof; I don't know how they compare with similar constructs in other languages.

@supercat I thought that  "she wasn't able to buy a car [yesterday]" is the past tense form of "she isn't able to buy a car [now]"/ "she is unable to buy a car [now]"

@Wittyhaire: Perhaps I should have said "would be the most natural way of converting the sentence 'she can't buy a car now' into the past tense.

All meanings but 2 could work, depending on context. The precise meaning could not be determined without additional context. There are other meanings not listed that could also be possible based on context.
1 and 4 are similar, and feel like a response to a claim that she bought a car, or intended to buy a car yesterday, by someone who has just been informed of her intent or attempt, whereas 3 feels like a meaning that would be used by a person who had knowledge of her intent or attempt.
Here is a sample dialog for each.
1.
Alice: I heard she bought a car yesterday.
Bob: She couldn't buy a car yesterday. She was here all day.
Alice: But that's what I heard.
Bob (checks the garage): Well, there is a new car in the garage. I wonder when she found the time.
3.
Bob: If I remember right, she was going to buy a car.
Alice: She couldn't buy a car yesterday. She got stuck in meetings.
Bob: That's the worst!
Alice: But she said she is going to try again tomorrow.
4.
Alice: She went to buy a car yesterday.
Bob: She couldn't buy a car yesterday. It was closed.
Alice: Oh! I didn't hear how it went.
Without context, none of those precise meanings is any more or less likely than any of the others. Or of the other possible meanings that could be carried by context, depending on who said or wrote it.
For instance, the standalone sentence doesn't imply a particular point of view, such as 'I.'
And it could also mean she didn't want to and didn't intend to. For example:
She couldn't buy a car yesterday. Surely they would have to admit that. And she still didn't want to today. In fact, she wondered, how did it get decided that she would be the one buying the car at all? Maybe she could convince Bob.

Meaning of  Punctuation (!?)

I am wondering what a standalone sentence 'She couldn't buy a car yesterday.' might mean:
'1. I don't know. There is no way I will believe that she bought a car yesterday.'.
'2. I don't know. It is possible that she didn't buy a car yesterday.'.
'3. I know that she tried to buy a car yesterday but failed.'.
'4. 'I know that she would have failed to buy a car yesterday even if she had tried to.'.

The standalone sentence ending in a period is clear (sentence 3) without any implied meaning.
If we change the punctuation at the end of the sentence, it implies a different meaning to it's original meaning:
She couldn't buy a car yesterday ?.
But if an exclamation mark or a question mark is used,  it shows disbelief or uncertainty and can convey the other meanings (sentences 1, 2, 4).
Ref. Collins dictionary

question mark.
in British English.
noun.
the punctuation mark ?, used at the end of questions and in other contexts where doubt or ignorance is implied
exclamation.
An exclamation is a sound, word, or sentence that is spoken suddenly, loudly, or emphatically and that expresses excitement, admiration, shock, or anger.

We can conclude -

A period (.) indicates that the statement is a fact.
A question mark (?) suggests inquiry or uncertainty.
An exclamation mark (!) expresses strong emotions, surprise, or disbelief.


This answer seems to focus on things not part of the question. The question didn't use interpunction. It feels like a mildly interesting comment ("Note that interpunction might modify the intended meaning")

@sehe I don't agree. It is necessary to understand why someone thought there would be different implied meanings. Asking to add a punctuation marksis similar to asking OP to add a "have".

Okay. That's an angle that I understand. I was completely missing the reason why you took that angle in the answer itself. Also, it still feels more like a comment.
